# How to program Select Menu's using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jscript

I'm new here to stack overflow and I've been searching on how to program drop-down menus in HTML and jscript. I've found a few decent examples but since I don't know much about jscript. I'm trying to integrate what I currently have to work with the labVIEW webservice. I will add the code I have below. Basically the buttons I have work perfectly with the javascript and the buttons. I want the select menus to work exactly the same so when I select a value it will call a function that will assign the value I need to the URL. For example when the start button is pushed it assigns start=1 in the url "digital" I want the same thing to happen for the select menu. When I select 511 from the dropdown menu I want it to assign the variable patternselector=1 in the url digital. Same thing for 2047 patternselector=0 in the url"digital" and so forth etc. I don't know what I'm doing at all so if someone could please help me right the example code/ function so I know how to program all of my other select menu's I have that will be awesome.

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    <select id="category" class="icon-menu" onchange="myFunction()"></select>
$(function() {
    function onDataReceived(data) {
        // update the displayed count
        $('#errorfreeseconds').text(String(data.Temperature).substring(0,4) + " degF");
    }

    function fetchData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "digital",
            type: "GET",
            //data: params,
            dataType: "json",
            success: onDataReceived
        });

        setTimeout(fetchData, 1000);
    }

    fetchData();

    $('#start').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "digital",
            type: "GET",
            data: "start=1",
            //dataType: "json",
            //success: onDataReceived
        });
    });

    $('#stop').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "digital",
            type: "GET",
            data: "stop=1",
            //dataType: "json",
            //success: onDataReceived
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="errorfreeseconds" style="font-size: 300%">0 Error Free Seconds</div>
</br>
<button id="start"style="font-size: 200%">Start Test</button>
<button id="stop" style="font-size: 200%">Stop Test</button>
<select>
<option value="2047">2047</option>
<option value="511">511</option>
<option value="63">63</option>
<option value="71">7:1</option>
<option value="31">3:1</option>
<option value="17">1:7</option>
<option value="14">1:4</option>
<option value="13">1:3</option>
<option value="11">1:1</option>
<option value="Space">Space</option>
<option value="Mark">Mark</option>
<option value="215">2^15-1</option>
<option value="220">2^20-1</option>
<option value="223">2^23-1</option>
<option value="QRSS">QRSS</option> 
</select>
<h3 style="color:green;">BAUD RATE(in Hertz)</h3>
<select>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the select element has `id="mySelect"` :

```
$('#mySelect').on('change', function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    // do whatever arcane thing you need to do with the value.
});
```